# Geoserver SLD external graphic path

Tags: geoserver, style, sld

```
<Rule>
    <PointSymbolizer>
     <Graphic>
       <ExternalGraphic>
         <OnlineResource
           xlink:type="simple"
           xlink:href="glass.png" />
         <Format>image/png</Format>
       </ExternalGraphic>
       <Size>28</Size>
     </Graphic>
   </PointSymbolizer>
</Rule>
```

I want to use external graphics on my layers. I styled with geoserver admin panel. But external graphics are not working. I put my image into **/var/www/geoserver/data/styles** folder.

I tried some href options but not worked.

- xlink:href="glass.png"
- xlink:href="file:///glass.png"
- xlink:href="/var/www/geoserver/glass.png"

I think another issue.

Comment: Your SLD looks very similar to "burg.sld" which is used in the demo layer "tiger:poi". There seems to be two ways for giving size but your way is also correct. Try to use your png symbol instead of "burg02.svg" for tiger:poi and check with layer preview that it is used. Change WMS Styles to "burg" from the extended options of the layer preview. Is  /var/www/geoserver/data your data_dir? Your last xlink with full path seems to have a typo - /data/ missing from the path.

Answer (score 9):

Check if you have created the style definition inside a workspace.

If you are in this situation you have to place the png image into ***$GEOSERVER_DATA_DIR/wokspaces/{Name}/styles*** directory or any subdirectory.

i.e if you upload the image into the directory:

***$GEOSERVER_DATA_DIR/workspaces/{yourWorkspace}/styles/images/earthquake.png***

Your sld must look like this

```
        <Rule>
          <Title>Red flag</Title>
          <PointSymbolizer>
            <Graphic>
              <ExternalGraphic>
                <OnlineResource xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="images/earthquake.png" />
                <Format>image/png</Format>
              </ExternalGraphic>
              <Size>
                <ogc:Literal>20</ogc:Literal>
              </Size>
            </Graphic>
          </PointSymbolizer>
        </Rule>
```

Answer (score 6):

This is modification of burg.sld that comes along with geoserver. I have provided earthquake.png in styles directory of GEOSERVER_DATA_DIRECTORY.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
    <StyledLayerDescriptor version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"
      xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld http://schemas.opengis.net/sld/1.0.0/StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd">
      <NamedLayer>
        <Name>redflag</Name>
        <UserStyle>
          <Name>burg</Name>
          <Title>A small red flag</Title>
          <Abstract>A sample of how to use an SVG based symbolizer</Abstract>

          <FeatureTypeStyle>
            <Rule>
              <Title>Red flag</Title>
              <PointSymbolizer>
                <Graphic>
                  <ExternalGraphic>
                    <OnlineResource xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="earthquake.png" />
                    <Format>image/png</Format>
                  </ExternalGraphic>
                  <Size>
                    <ogc:Literal>20</ogc:Literal>
                  </Size>
                </Graphic>
              </PointSymbolizer>
            </Rule>

          </FeatureTypeStyle>
        </UserStyle>
      </NamedLayer>
    </StyledLayerDescriptor>
```