# Geoserver SLD creation using a local image

Tags: geoserver, sld

Using [this documentation](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld-extensions/pointsymbols.html) I have made the below SLD file, attempting to use an svg that I obtained from [here](http://learninggis.com/gis-resources/qgis-oilandgas-symbol) I have moved the svg into `/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/geoserver/data/styles` but the image will not render when previewing in the geoserver style editor (the return is a grey square).  I've gone through this [SE](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/122654/geoserver-sld-external-graphic-path) post and tried to reverse engineer it and have also used a direct path the result are the same.  What am I missing?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor version="1.0.0" 
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd" 
 xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" 
 xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" 
 xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <!-- a Named Layer is the basic building block of an SLD document -->
  <NamedLayer>
    <Name>default_point</Name>
    <UserStyle>
    <!-- Styles can have names, titles and abstracts -->
      <Title>Default Point</Title>
      <Abstract>A sample style that draws a point</Abstract>
      <!-- FeatureTypeStyles describe how to render different features -->
      <!-- A FeatureTypeStyle for rendering points -->
      <FeatureTypeStyle>
        <Rule>
          <Name>rule1</Name>
          <Title>platform</Title>
          <Abstract>Platform icon</Abstract>
            <PointSymbolizer>
                <Graphic>
                    <ExternalGraphic>
                        <OnlineResource xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="26 SUSPENDED-OILSHOW.svg"/>
                        <Format>image/svg+xml</Format>
                    </ExternalGraphic>
                    <Size>20</Size>
                </Graphic>
          </PointSymbolizer>
        </Rule>
      </FeatureTypeStyle>
    </UserStyle>
  </NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

I was able to get it to work with a direct path `xlink:href="file:////var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/geoserver/data/styles/26%20SUSPENDED-OILSHOW.svg"`  Why will it not work with a relative path?

Comment: Have you tried encoding the space as `%20` in the relative path?

Comment: Yes I have tried that

Comment: have you tried not having a space in the path?

Comment: yes I have changed the file to "26SUSPENDED-OILSHOW.svg" and updated the sld accordingly.  I'm starting to think that my GEOSERVER_DATA_DIR is not what I think it is if it works with absolute paths but not relative.... Where can I check that?

Comment: look in the `server status` menu (top left) and the first line tells you where your data dir is

Comment: I had same problem. I just put a images into `data_dir/styles` and my url to resource `<OnlineResource xlink:href="000D000072F3_0.svg"/>` and it works.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.

In my case, the relative path was wrong.

Check in Server Status (first option in the left menu). There you can see the data directory, and your relative path for the image must start from there.

In your case, if the data directory is `/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/geoserver/data`, the image relative path should be `/styles/26%20SUSPENDED-OILSHOW.svg`