# Can't get Icon by URL

Tags: java, geotools

I want to put barbs on my map and everything is ok for the most maps until such error occurred

> org.geotools.referencing.factory.DeferredAuthorityFactory disposeBackingStore
>   INFO: Disposing class org.geotools.referencing.factory.epsg.hsql.ThreadedHsqlEpsgFactory backing store
>   org.geotools.renderer.style.ImageGraphicFactory getIcon
>   WARNING: Unable to read image at http://windbarbs.kl.com.ua/small_pic/icons8-wind-speed-less-1-32.png : Can't create an ImageInputStream!
>
> org.geotools.renderer.lite.StreamingRenderer fireErrorEvent
>   SEVERE: GC overhead limit exceeded
>   java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded

Comment: Please take the [Tour], which emphasizes the importance of asking One question per Question. Your title is for the second question, and the first question is missing details on the exact nature of the sudden failure.

Comment: You 2nd question is a duplicate of https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/122654/geoserver-sld-external-graphic-path

Comment: I am very sorry, but my scnd question is not the same. I am not using GeoServer, I am using only GeoTools. Should I integrate GeoTools with some server to avoid problems with creating images as external graphic by url? I really don't know wthat to do further. I checked that sld schema is readind and checked rhat url also is reading, but I can't render my images...